# How to do continuous integration on feature branches

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

In our company we use git flow and use continuous integration.

That means:

- When someone commit on `develop`, our develop server builds to develop.domain.com
- When someone commit on `master`, we build to production

This works great, but not for features.

We often have multiple features, which requires to be tested by the rest of the company.

So I want to say:

"Build `/feature/my-feature/` to `feature_1.domain.com`", so anyone on our interal network can access that feature very easily.

How can you do this?

**Possible solutions I could think off**

*Build own tool*:

We're considering to build our own tool that authenticates with Github, and then manually fetches the repo and build solution to a given URL.

That just seems really weird - it seems to hack continuous integration.

*Feature toggles*:

The most common answer seems to be to use feature toggles, but that doesn't make it easy for other people to test / turn features on/off.

Technologies: Git (GitHub), CruiseControl, Sourcetree, .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just throwing something out there.. Add a ccnet project called BuildToFeature_X. Use ccnet parameters to control what gets built and where. The parameters would be:

1. FeatureNumber - The domain to post to. You used 1 in your example.
2. Branch URL - Which version control branch to checkout and build.

The ccnet project checks out Branch URL and builds it to feature_[FeatureNumber].domain.com.

http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Parameters